# find a matching line in a txt with python

Tags: python, string

I can test whether a string is in a text file with python like the following:

```
if(pdfname in open(filename).read()):
   //do something
```

But how I can I verify it? I want the matching line show up. Thanks.

Comment: How do you _verify_ it? If you don't trust Python to work correctly with that snippet, why would you trust it not to lie and print out random rubbish with `pdfname` in it? :-)

Comment: I just print out the file and do it myself.

Comment: @paxidiablo I just used another method to test matching line, it turned out the code was wrong, as compared to this version, which is probably right. Not that I don't trust python, but I don't trust code from google search very much, so I need to verify it.

Comment: remember comparison is case sensitive by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print out the relevant lines with the second `for` statement below, which I've added to your existing code for illustration:

```
pdfname = "statementConcentrator"
if (pdfname in open("line56.good").read()):
    print "Found it"

lineNum = 0
for line in open("line56.good").readlines():
    lineNum = lineNum + 1
    if pdfname in line:
        print "#%5d: %s"%(lineNum, line[:-1])
```

This outputs your current line plus my output for verification:

```
Found it
#  115:  statementConcentrator=0
```

and, checking that file, that is indeed the line it's found on.

Note that you can simply use a script as follows to do both jobs in a single loop:

```
pdfname = "statementConcentrator"
lineNum = 0
count = 0
for line in open("line56.good").readlines():
    lineNum = lineNum + 1
    if pdfname in line:
        print "#%5d: %s"%(lineNum, line[:-1])
        count = count + 1
print "Found on %d line(s)."%(count)
```

Comment: Rather inefficient to go over the file twice.

Comment: @Amber, I'm not advocating going over the file twice, my answer was just the end bit which I added to the existing script for illustration. I'll clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Just loop over the file:

```
handle = open(filename, 'r')

for line in handle:
  if pdfname in line:
    print line

handle.close()
```